# Is there a way to calculate the width between a centered div and the edge of the screen?

Tags: css

Is there a way to calculate the width between a centered div and the edge of the screen? Please see the photo for a better understanding. [Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dt3p.png)

Comment: By *calculate* you mean in JavaScript? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I meant only in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

I see from your comment that you are looking for a pure CSS way of doing this. Unfortunately, this isn't possible with Vanilla CSS. The JavaScript method below is still going to be your best bet.

### ORIGINAL

So, assuming you are looking for JavaScript, here is the function you are looking for:

```js
Element.getBoundingClientRect()
```

You can read more about how this function works on [MDM Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Basically, you give it an element to look at and it will return a JS Object with all the parameters you need *(namely x, y, width, height, top, bottom, left, and right)*

Here is an example:

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('div');
let rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

let text = document.querySelector('p');

let str = 
    "X: " +
    rect.x + "px, Y: " + 
    rect.y + "px\nWidth: " + 
    rect.width + "px, Height: " + 
    rect.height + "px\nTop: " + 
    rect.top + "px, Bottom: " + 
    rect.bottom + "px\nRight: " + 
    rect.right + "px, Left: " + 
    rect.left + "px";

text.innerText = str;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  
  font-family: "Segoe UI Variable Display", system-ui, ui-rounded, sans-serif;
}

div {
  width: 75vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: #8CB0C8;
  border: 2px solid #688394;
  border-radius: 32px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is our div!</p>
</div>
```

I hope this helps and please check out the [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [Minimum, Reproducible Example Outline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get browser window width, subtract container width and divide the result by 2. Pass this to the browser console on StackOverflow to check

```
(window.innerWidth - document.querySelector("body>.container").offsetWidth) / 2
```